# Вызов функции, неизвестной на этапе компиляции

Tags: c++, c

```
void abc_0(int, long);
void abc_1(char &);
int abc_2();
int abc_3(int, char*);
//... и т.д.

void * func_array[100];
func_array[0] = abc_0;
func_array[1] = abc_1;
func_array[2] = abc_2;
func_array[3] = abc_3;
//... и т.д.

char data[100];
// В data лежит информация описывающая прототип функции и данные к ней. 
// Навскидку примерно такого вида:
// data[0] -> Номер индекса с адресом вызываемой функции из массива func_array ( например = 13 ) 
// data[1] -> Размер переменной под возвращаемое значение ( например = 4 -> sizeof int )
// data[2] -> Количество параметров ( например = 2 )
// data[3,4] -> Размер параметров ( например = 4 и 8 -> sizeof int / long )
// data[5-9] -> Место под возвращаемое значение
// data[10-13] -> Само значение параметра #1 с указаной размерностью ( data[3] )
// data[14-21] -> Само значение параметра #2 с указаной размерностью ( data[4] ) 
// Все данные являются правильными, по отношению к вызываемой функции.
// Также все функции являются частью самой программы и ни откуда не заимствуются.
```

Как корректно вызвать функцию по данным из приведённого примера?

Псевдо-кодом визуально вызов можно представить так:

```
// data[5-9] = func_array[ data[0] ]( data[10-13], data[14-21] );
```

Comment: Вариант 1. Если вы знаете к-во параметров, то просто обьявляете `int _cdecl f(...)`, кастите и пробрасываете только параметы, и быть может тип функции. Все функции, ка которые будете ссылаться должны быть `_cdecl` (соглашение о вызове).

Comment: Вариант 2. switch (тип) {   ((каст функции к нужной)f)(параметры нужные) }. Вариант 3, можно что-то выиграть сократить используя template или define + 1 или 2 метод.

Comment: думаю, Вам стоит прочитать, как работают компиляторы. Многие вопросы просто отпадут сразу.

Comment: В прошлом вопросе уже выяснили, что С/C++ являются языками со статической типизацией и для вызова любой функции ее тип, как и тип всех ее аргументов должен быть задан на этапе компиляции. Соответственно средствами этих языков такое сделать не получится.

Comment: Вариант 4. Берёте `switch (номер функции)` и внутри `switch` реализуйте 100 случаев. Используя дополнительные `case 1: {   } ;break;` скобки вы можете создать локальные переменные, которые будут актуальные только для каждого уникального случая. Не забудте в конце `case` добавить `break`, `contiunue` если в цикле, или `return`.

Comment: 5. Возможно само эффективно будет задействовать ассемблер, но за вас это не напишут (программу под все 100 случаев), плюс надо знать варианты действий. Под 4 случая я напишу допустим, но она возможно не сработает для других случаев.

Comment: А вы данные копировать умеете?

Comment: @nick_n_a
Спасибо за предложенные варианты.

В целом switch - это наиболее очевидное решение подобных вопросов, обычно оно и самое лучшее в сегменте простоты/скорости. Но оно и также имеет существенный недостаток: его можно использовать лишь с константным набором функций/прототипов, и в случаях когда этот набор динамический или часто меняющийся в ходе написания, вариант такой увы уже не подходит.

_cdecl - что-то интересное, поинтересуюсь в ближайшее время, еще раз спасибо.

5. В принципе я изначально предполагал, что средствами языка такое невозможно сделать, и используя......

Comment: ..... и используя ассемблерные вставки - как скорее единственный возможный способ, решить такую задачу.

К сожалению ассемблер знаю плохо, как и тонкости работы под капотом, поэтому я был бы признателен, если бы вы могли направить меня в правильное русло. Даже какой ни будь пример ассемблерной вставки, чтобы понять куда и как копать.
====
Если же вы планируете добавить еще какую либо информацию, то думаю ваши предложенные варианты уже можно организовать до вполне цельного ответа.

Comment: Я вам показал пример без ассемблерных вставок, надеюсь байты копировать вы знаете как. Без копирования байт.

Comment: У вас какие-то требования к системе (32/64bit, Linux/Windows, x86/arm/...) есть?

Comment: @avp, лично мои требования достаточно серьёзные, проще говоря "работать должно почти везде", но в данном вопросе это не столь важно, так как вопрос ориентирован в большей степени на обобщение. Чтобы каждый мог найти чтото полезное и использовать её, специализировав под свои требования.
Так что если у вас есть любые предложения, то прошу... Больше информации по теме в одном месте, только в плюс для всех.

Answer (score 4):

В общем случае, тех данных, которые у вас есть о функции, недостаточно чтобы ее вызвать.

А именно, недостаточно знать размеры возвращаемого типа и типов параметров. Нужно знать сами типы.

- Передача параметров в функцию может требовать вызова копирующих/перемещающих конструкторов, для которых нужно знать типы параметров.
- [Calling convetion](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BE_%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5) функции определяется не только размерами типов ([пример](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58339165/2752075)).

Comment: А почему не комент?))

Comment: @nick_n_a Так я ответил на вопрос? Автор спрашивает "как вызвать функцию, имея указатель на нее и такие-то данные". Ответ - никак.

Answer (score 1):

Вариант _cdecl влоб. Реализовать для 8 это чудо можно. Для x86 реализация будет такая, выравнивание идёт по 4-ке. Для x64 выравнивание по 8-ке. Для не x86 и не x64 это работать с большой вероятностью не будет. Тут использованы "приколы" платформы x86. Зная что __int64 компилятор реализует возврат через пару eax edx, а параметры __int64 "бьёт" на два int (8 байт), можно применить преобразование. Избыточность означает что мы передаём всё с избытком, а заберём только то что надо. Это упрощает написание кода в разы.

Примитивная "избыточная" реализация такая.

```
// Обьявляем функцию, обязательно _cdecl  
void _cdecl abc_0(int, long); // тут три параметра_x86 по 4 байта или два разных размеров
void _cdecl abc_1(char &); // тут адрес 4 байта. Что бы адрес не потерялся - аккуратно тестить, читать устройство переменных.
// Обьявляем избыточный тип, и массив
 typedef __int64 _cdecl (*TF_8CDECL)(...);
 TF_8CDECL func_array[] = { (TF_8CDECL) abc_0, и т д }
```

Вариант 1

```
//----------------------------
// Теперь создаём программу
int pars[100]; // Задаём массив для проброшеных параметров.
int param_count=0; // Преобразованое к-во параметров.
for ( /*что-то*/) { // Цикл по параметрам
    pars[param_count++] = младшая часть аргумента от 1 до 4 байта;
    if (размер аргумента > 4) pars[param_count++] =  старшая часть аргумента;
    // Для x64 if не нужен.
   }
```

Дальше два варианта, правильный, и быстрый. Покажу быстрый избыточный.

```
// Обьявляем избыточный результат
__int64 result;
// Вызов из x86, для двух параметров надо 2*2 = 4 аргумента, для 3 - 6, 4 -8 и т д
// Для x64 число аргументов и параметров будет одинаково.
result = func_array[номер ф-ции](pars[0],pars[1],pars[2],pars[3]); // Для двух
// это был "избыточный" вызов. Функция возьмет только те аргументы 
// которые ей надо, главное что бы для самого большого param_count
// случая все параметры были. _cdecl соглашение - разрешает это.
//можно через case упростить, но тогда программа станет сложнее, 
// и лучше уже через swith-case всё реализовать.
 memcpy ( нужный байт из data, result, размер результата);
 // Готово.
```

Если вы поняли как работает программа выше, и параметры у вас выровняты по границам 4 байта т.е. размер параметра строго 4 или 8,  то саму программу выше можно упростить так (всё то же без пояснений) почти до 3-х строк (для x86 будет работать, для x64 не будет потому что выровнять надо по границе 8 а не 4):

```
// Теперь создаём программу вариант 2
void ваша_фция(char * data){
volatile int * pars2 = (int *) &data[номер байта, где начинается содержимое 1-го параметра т.е. 10 ];  
__int64 result =  func_array[номер ф-ции](pars2[0],pars2[1],pars2[2],pars2[3]);// вызов 2 параметра x86
 memcpy ( нужный байт из data, result, размер результата); // Или другим способом
}
```

Думаю после трассировки, должно заработать. Жертвуя немного скоростью, мы упрощаем код.

---

UDP. Вижу что _cdecl не все понимают. Изначально си и с++ в 90% случаев использует вызов _cdecl по умолчанию. Соглашение о вызове можно менять в опциях компилятора. Разные среды и разные компиляторы в разных режимах могут по умолчанию использовать другие соглашения о вызове, например __fastcall (что бы ускорить программу, т.к. предпочтительно всё передаётся в регистрах)  __stdcall и много других (зависит от компилятора). Если вы вызовете __cdecl из прототипа с больщим числом параметров функцию с меньшим числом параметров - сбоя не будет. (Если наоборот - в аргументах будет мусор, но сбоя от самого вызова не будет). Но для соглашения __stdcall у вас программа закончится сбоем. Для __fastcall тоже большая вероятность что вы получите сбой. Если вы в прототипе и в функции используете разные соглашения о вызове, то в 99% случаев будет сбой. Соглашение _cdecl формирует такой стак-фрейм который совместим между такими же фреймами с разным числом аргументов, что позволяет использовать его для функций с переменным числом аргуметов, например `printf`,`scanf`, а так же позволяет делать то что я показал в этом примере.

Если вы не указываете тип соглашения о вызове, компилятор подставляет то, которое по умолчанию. В 90% случаев работать будет. Но так как не всегда соглашение _cdecl по умолчанию, то может попастся случай, когда программа почему-то не заработает, и с 10-го раза всёравно не заработает. Будет не сразу понятно почему. Поэтому я советую `_cdecl` поставить явно в таких преобразованиях.

Что бы компилятор не упрощал код есть ключевое слово `volatile`.

---

Для кроссплатформы этот код переделать можно.

1. Для этого нужно создать `pars` с размером элементов равных размеру элемента стека (часто бывает 16, 32, 64). В pars нужно записать значения параметров из data, если значение из data не помещается в одном элементе, то размещать его в нескольких элементах кратных степени двойки (например __int64 разобьётся на 4 ре int16). В вызов надо будет подставить то число элементов, которые будет в "стек" pars сгенерировано максимально. (для стека 16, 2-х параметров, и возможности int64 это будет 64/16*2 = 8 элементов. При заполнении pars нужно учесть litte-indian и big-indian.
2. Вызов приёдется разбить на несколько (три в даном сучае) по числу возвращаемых параметров, и вызывать  `void f(...)`,`int32 f(...)`,`int64 f(...)` в отдельных ветках, потому что соглашение о размещении возвращаемых параметрах на других платформах может не быть взаимосовместимым, как для x86 и x64. При копировании данных назад в data нужно так же учесть litte-indian и big-indian.

P.S. Самая "быстрая" но громоздкая - будет реализация через `switch(номер функции) { case 1: {} break; ... case 100: {} break; }` и все сто случаев.
Так же рекомендую почитать [Машина тьюнинга](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0_%D0%A2%D1%8C%D1%8E%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0)

Comment: Думаю ваш вариант можно еще улучшить в специфике кроссплатформенности:

К примеру можно заменить _cdecl и заместо создать простую обёртку для каждой функции, с однотипным прототипом. Типа "void func_for_abc1(char * data);" . обязанность этой обёртки лишь в том, чтобы явно задействовать прототип вызываемой функции, также за взятие/перенос из "data" параметров для функции и запись в "data" её возвращаемого значения.

Соответственно всю работу уже берёт на себя компилятор, и мы не теряем здесь кроссплатформенность и не получаем всякие ограничения.
Хотя это и немного затратнее по времени.

Comment: Если вы хотите сделать из этого варианта кросс-платформу то надо 1) создать три протопипа функции `void _cdecl f(...)`,`int32 _cdecl f(...)`, `int64 _cdecl f(...)` и при вызове делать ветвление на три случая. Поскольку не все системы ответ смогут вернуть в регистры. 2) нужно знать сколько байт выравнивание стека. Это нужно учесть в `for`. 3)нужно учесть система little-indian или big-indian.

Comment: Обычно длы упрощения мы ставим условия, и в рамках условий пишем. Как правило 99% программ пишуться под x86 чуть реже для x64. Если вы хотите в ответах кроссплатформу - нужно явно это указывать.

Comment: Поэтому и не указывал, чтобы вопрос был наиболее обобщенным, то есть для всех, а не только для себя. За дополнительное уточнение с _cdecl также благодарствую.

Comment: Если по умолчанию  компилятор считат что всё _cdecl то `void func_for_abc1(char * data);` и `void _cdecl f(...);` будут почти эквивалентны. Если нет, то программа может не заработать при разном числе аргументов. Есть ещё __stdcall и __fastcall (и много других) которые не совместимы с _cdecl

Answer (score 1):

Если ограничить задачу языком Си, системой с передачей параметров в регистрах (это x86-64 и многие 64 и 32-bit RISC), и функциями, возвращающими  int  с одним или двумя аргументами (первый (или единственный) аргумент типа `int` (м.б. также signed/unsigned char или short) или `double`, второй `long long` (м.б. unsigned) или `double`, то можно предложить весьма простую схему.

Прототипы используемых функций -- `typedef int (*func)();` -- т.е. функция с любым количеством параметров.

Далее определяем переменные:

```
  func func_array[] = {f1, f2, f3, f4, foosqrt, 0};
  char data[22] = {0};

  volatile uint32_t *pia1 = (volatile uint32_t *)&data[10];
  volatile uint64_t *pia2 = (volatile uint64_t *)&data[14];
  volatile double *pda2 = (volatile double *)&data[14];
  volatile int *res = (volatile int *)&data[5];
```

для доступа к  массиву `data[]` с описанием  вызова произвольной функции.

Тогда сам вызов осуществляется так:

```
*res = func_array[(int)data[0]](*pia1, *pia2, *pda2);
```

Вот пример (2 файла)

Файл с функциями:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char
f1 (char c)
{
  printf("f1(char): '%c' 0x%02x\n", c, c);

  return ++c;
}

int
f2 (int i, long long ll)
{
  int res = ll / (i ? i : 1);
  printf("f2(int, long long): %d %lld = %d\n", i, ll, res);

  return res;
}


int
f4 (int i, int i2)
{
  printf("f4(int, int): %d %d = %d\n", i, i2, i + i2);

  return i + i2;
}

int
f3 (int i, double d)
{
  float res = d / (i ? i : 1);
  printf("f3(int, double): %d %f = %f\n", i, d, res);

  int rc;
  float *p = (float *)&rc;
  *p = res;
  
  return rc;
}

#include <math.h>

int
foosqrt (double d)
{
  float res = sqrt(d);
  printf("fsqrt(double): %f = %f\n", d, res);

  int rc;
  float *p = (float *)&rc;
  *p = res;
  
  return rc;
}
```

Файл с программой их вызова:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef int (*func)();

extern int f1(), f2(), f3(), f4(), foosqrt();
/*
  realy
  char  f1(char);
  int   f2(int, long long);
  int   f3(int, double); // float result packed to int
  int   f4(int, int);
  int   foosqrt(double); //  float result packed to int

 */

int main (int ac, char *av[])
{
  func func_array[] = {f1, f2, f3, f4, foosqrt, 0};
  char data[22] = {0};

  volatile uint32_t *pia1 = (volatile uint32_t *)&data[10];
  volatile uint64_t *pia2 = (volatile uint64_t *)&data[14];
  volatile double *pda2 = (volatile double *)&data[14];
  volatile int *res = (volatile int *)&data[5];

  int foono, ii;
  double d;
  long long ll;
  
  while (fputs("fno int dbl llng > ", stdout),
         scanf("%d %i %lf %lld", &foono, &ii, &d, &ll) == 4) {
    if (foono < 0 || foono > 4) {
      puts("wrong foo");
      continue;
    }
    data[0] = foono;

    switch (foono) {
    case 2:
      *pia1 = ii;
    case 4:
      *pda2 = d;
      break;
    default:
      *pia1 = ii;
      *pia2 = ll;      
    }

    *res = func_array[(int)data[0]](*pia1, *pia2, *pda2);

    printf("result: ");
    switch (foono) {
    case 0:
      printf("'%c' 0x%02x\n", data[5], *pia1);
      break;
    case 1:
    case 3:
      printf("%d\n", *res);
      break;
    case 2:
    case 4:
      printf("%f\n", *(float *)res);
    }
    puts("");
  }

  return puts("End") == EOF;
}
```

Транслируем и запускаем

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ gcc tttf.c ttt.c -O3 -Wall -lm
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ ./a.out
fno int dbl llng > 0 0x40 0 0
f1(char): '@' 0x40
result: 'A' 0x40

fno int dbl llng > 1 1000 0 123456789000
f2(int, long long): 1000 123456789000 = 123456789
result: 123456789

fno int dbl llng > 2 10 1234.56 0
f3(int, double): 10 1234.560000 = 123.456001
result: 123.456001

fno int dbl llng > 3 100 0 200
f4(int, int): 100 200 = 300
result: 300

fno int dbl llng > 4 0 144.0 0
fsqrt(double): 144.000000 = 12.000000
result: 12.000000

fno int dbl llng > .
End
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$
```

Проверял в

```
avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$ gcc --version; uname -a; cat /etc/issue
gcc (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04) 7.5.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

Linux avp-desktop 5.4.0-71-generic #79~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Mar 25 05:45:39 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia \n \l

avp@avp-desktop:~/avp/hashcode$
```

Что не понятно, спрашивайте в комментариях

Comment: До конца не уверен, но MSVS запрещает в "func func_array[] = {f1, f2, f3, f4, foosqrt, 0};" делать преобразование прототипов функции одной к другой. В принципе оно и логично, и я немножко удивлён тому, что GCC вообще такое позволяет, хотя я скорее всего чего то не знаю, но не суть.
В целом ваш вариант, это одна из разновидностей через switch с использованием группировки индексов вызываемых функций по типам входных параметров. Для большого числа функций с одинаковыми типами параметров это даст выигрыш, но для приличного набора функций это быстро превратиться в неподдерживаемый в будущем код.

Comment: Это можно было бы тоже улучшить немного, отказавшись от ручного проставления параметров в разделе со "switch", заменив это на массив прототипов с массивом функций - вида: "func_array[прототип][индекс функции]".
И тем самым вызывать нужную функцию по индексу прототипа и индексу самой функции через оператор "switch". В целом код станет гораздо читабельнее, да и еще и наверняка по шустрее.
Спасибо за ваше предложение.

Comment: @NewTech, очевидно же, что switch тут нужен исключительно в целях интерактивного ввода данных. Наверное, в "боевом варианте" будет одна часть кода, которая формирует массивы data, исходя из логики обработки для **отложенного выполнения**, которые интерпретируются другой частью, которая  и вызывает "заказанные" первой частью функции. *Иначе в чем вообще смысл всей этой затеи?* (кстати, никакой группировки по типам я не предусматривал. Эта штука будет работать в любом порядке)

Comment: отвечая на ваш интерес: "в чем вообще смысл всей этой затеи?" - вероятно сразу может быть и не понятно, но как минимум один смысл явно стоит заморочек, и стоящий как минимум быть взятым на заметку. Это: сделать процесс анализа и дизассемблирования скомпилированного кода сущим кошмаром для умельцев. Думаю вы бы и сами очень сильно расстроились, если бы ваш продукт с 2-5 годами усилий потраченных на него, взял бы и получил бы свой заветный Кряк.

Comment: @NewTech, откровенно говоря, нет, не расстроился бы. Более того,  я считаю, что программы (как и другие нематериальные объекты) вообще должны быть бесплатно доступны всем (вместе с исходниками)